How to install flatpak-builder in rhel docker (ubi)?
For context: I'm trying to crossbuild wezterm-mux-server to use it on remote servers of my company that run RHEL 9.2+. Since I don't have full root access I want to crossbuild them on my local machine and then copy over the binaries. The problem is that the build needs some distro-related dependencies, e.g. for rhel it needs flatpak-builder. Now how do I get flatpak-builder into the rhel docker image (ubi)? It doesn't seem to be included in any of the upstream repos that is queried by yum.
Here are my steps so far:
Pull and execut docker image:
docker login registry.redhat.io # Use your red hat usename and password
docker pull registry.redhat.io/ubi9/ubi:9.5-1732804088
docker run -v $PWD:/opt -it --entrypoint /bin/bash registry.redhat.io/ubi9/ubi:9.5-1732804088

From within the image execute:
yum install flatpak-builder

Which results in the following error message
[root@00cef48d6bb3 /]# yum install flatpak-builder
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Red Hat Universal Base Image 9 (RPMs) - BaseOS                                               1.4 MB/s | 525 kB     00:00
Red Hat Universal Base Image 9 (RPMs) - AppStream                                            461 kB/s | 2.3 MB     00:05
Red Hat Universal Base Image 9 (RPMs) - CodeReady Builder                                    1.0 MB/s | 281 kB     00:00
No match for argument: flatpak-builder
Error: Unable to find a match: flatpak-builder

Building from source is not really an option since flatpak-builder itself needs a ton of additional dependencies (I don't want to build the whole dependency tree manually). So my prefered way is to do it with a package manager. However since I'm a newbie to RHEL I have no idea how to add a new online repository or how to find out which online repositories even contain flatpak-builder?
